# Creating a Diagonal Mask Effect

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm wondering how I would go about creating a diagonal mask like effect. The mask would show all in the top left corner, hide the middle part, then show all in the bottom right corner. In the example, the mask would be on the .container element and mask out any children in the div as well.

I've looked at resources online, [specifically here](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/bNVaRO), and can't get this effect to work on non-image elements. Is there a different type of property to use in CSS to achieve this effect? I was thinking maybe SVG, but I'd like it to adapt to the width and height of the element, and wasn't sure how to pull that off.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qm58yjgn/6/)**

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  mask: gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
            color-stop(0.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),
            color-stop(0.35,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),
            color-stop(0.50,  rgba(0,0,0,0)),
            color-stop(0.65,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),
            color-stop(1.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1)));
}

.shape {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```

The mask would look something like this image.

[image: mask example]

Comment: How do you mean - "to get it work with HTML elements"? Literary to create some kind of opacity directly on div, for example?

Comment: Looks like I message up, I have clarified the question. I am looking to mask out parts of .container element. What I meant was I am unable to have this effect work on non-image elements.

Comment: you should replace mask with -webkit-mask since inside you are using -webkit .. then use the version without webkit

Comment: Did not mean to include the -webkit-, would the non-webkit version be simply mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mask-image works here. **[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qm58yjgn/7/)**.

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, transparent 35% , transparent 50%, transparent 65%, black 100%);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, transparent 35% , transparent 50%, transparent 65%, black 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe so?

```css
.container {
  width:50%;
  height:50%; 
 
 }
.rect1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg class="the-svg"  viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
  
  <defs>
 
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="1.0" y1="0" y2="1.0" >
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color= "white"/>
      <stop offset="35%" stop-color="white"/>
   <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black"/>
   <stop offset="65%" stop-color="white"/>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white"/>
      </linearGradient>

  </defs>
   <rect class="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  />
  
</svg>

</div>
```

The solution is adaptive and works in all browsers, including Edge

Comment: The shape looks right, but how would you apply this as a mask to the container element, and have it mask out the parts of the child elements?

Comment: @DRB It is possible to make a mask. Please draw as it should look